# Обратный вывод данных из таблици

Tags: php, sql

Помогите сделать вывод данных из таблицы в обратном порядке, сейчас я их вывожу в прямом порядке. Можно ли сделать кнопку для удаления строки, рядом со стройкой которую можно удалить?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
  <?php
        require_once 'connection.php'; // подключаем скрипт
        
        $link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database) 
            or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link)); 
            
        $query ="SELECT * FROM phones";
        
        $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link)); 
        if($result)
        {
            $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result); // количество полученных строк
            
            echo "<table><tr><th>Id</th><th>Модель</th><th>Производитель</th></tr>";
            for ($i = 0 ; $i < $rows ; ++$i)
            {
                $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
                echo "<tr>";
                    for ($j = 0 ; $j < 3 ; ++$j) echo "<td>$row[$j]</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
            echo "</table>";
            
            // очищаем результат
            mysqli_free_result($result);
        }
        
        mysqli_close($link);
        ?>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Для сортировки почитайте про [order by](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp)

Comment: спасибо, помогло

Comment: откуда вы все понабрались этого `or die(...)` ?

Comment: @teran А по моему красиво смотрится `or die`, может из перла заимствовали, там это стандартная и можно сказать рекомендуемая практика

Comment: @Mike ошибка должна быть нормально обработана, занесена в лог, пользователю должно быть показана какая-то информативная страница. А таким образом либо пустой экран на выходе, либо еще веселее SQL код запроса выводят. Еще если замешают хтмл с пхп вместе, то по середине вывод страниц может оборваться с разъехавшейся версткой.

Comment: @teran ну в этом смысле конечно лучше пользователю нормально сообщать. А откуда берут ... Да хоть из официальной документации на mysql https://dev.mysql.com/doc/apis-php/en/apis-php-mysqli.construct.html На старые функции mysql на php.net в документации то же самое. И думаю всяких учебников с такими примерами более чем достаточно. И с другой стороны, учитывая, что раз в неделю тут встречается вопрос в котором ТС не может понять в чем проблема из за того, что обработки ошибок вообще нет, die не самое плохое что может быть :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Чтение с БД</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    //Получаем параметры для доступа к БД
    $db_config = require 'db.php';

    //Подключение к БД
    $connection = mysqli_connect($db_config['host'], $db_config['user'], $db_config['password'], $db_config['dbname']); 

    //Проверяем на ошибку соединения
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
    {
        printf("Не удалось подключиться: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();//Останавливаем дальнейшую работу скрипта
    }

    //Получаем результат запроса
    if ($result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM phones")) 
    {
        //Собираем весь вывод в переменную
        $output ='
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <th>id</th>
                <th>Модель</th>
                <th>Производитель</th>
            </tr>';

        //Для каждого записи с таблицы создаем строку в таблице
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
        {
            $output .= "
            <tr>
                <td>{$row['id']}</td>
                <td>{$row['model']}</td>
                <td>{$row['company']}</td>
            </tr>";
        }
        $output .= "
        </table>
    ";

        //Отображаем данные пользователю
        echo $output;

        //Освобождаем память
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    }

    //Закрываем соединение
    mysqli_close($connection);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Пароль и прочие настройки вынесите в отдельный файл "db.php" =>

```
<?php
    return [
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'user' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'dbname' => 'testdb',
    ];
```

Что-то вроде этого сделайте. Забудьте про for $i++. Почти всё начинается с нулевого элемента и перебор лучше через while или foreach.
Ловить ошибки для mysqli можно, но они не являются критическими. Их не поймает try-catch, тут нужно переопределять обработчик ошибок.